# How to data bind combobox inside a user control?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am working on a winforms project using the c# language. I have a problem about databinding a combobox that is inside a usercontrol. The connection is ok at design time because it can preview data. However, during run time, it will not show any bound data. By the way, I only used the combobox's smart tag because I don't have a code to bind it. :D

Just follow what I did so that you will get my point. :)

I have a windows form (**Form1**) and put a button (**button1**) and a panel (**panel1**) on it.

Then I added a user control (**UserControl1**) to the project. And then I put a combobox (**comboBox1**) to the usercontrol. I used the combobox's smart tag to bind data into it.

Here's what I did to the combobox using the smart tag:
I checked **Use Data Bound Items**. On the datasource, I clicked **Add Project Data Source** and the Configuration Wizard appeared. I choose **Database, Dataset** and I included the sensitive data to the connection string. Then I chose **tblCategory** with 2 columns, **ID** and **Category**, as Database Objects. I named the dataset as **dbDataSet**. Then I clicked finish. Then I added **Category** as the Display Member and **ID** as the Value Member.

I added a code to **button1**'s Click event. Here's the code:
    new UserControl1().Parent = this.panel1;
This code will add the user control to the form whenever the button is clicked.

But the problem is, no bound data will show during run time.

Can you give me a code that can bind data to the combobox in this kind of setup?

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Yes, there's probably a way to solve this problem, but you have to show us some more details and include some code that highlights the problem.

Comment: `using the smart tag` ? wut -> I can easily help you but you show no code nor actual question (only thing I know is data doesnt show...)

Comment: As @Tanner says we need a lot more detail to help.  One thing to note is that ComboBoxes are usually bound in two ways; once to data containing the list of possible values (usually through the DataSource property) and once to the actual chosen value (usually through the SelectedValue property).  How exactly are you using this ComboBox?

Comment: sorry guys i'm just a newbie here. just let me edit my question for further clarification. :)

Comment: NOT enough info as people say; 
To Bind a control - comboBox (cbx) in your case - you have to bind on Initialization to some source:
'cbx.DataSource = someTable; 
 cbx.DisplayMember = "some field name";
 cbx.ValueMember = " ID column";
'
and then as on some Event when you pass back some data connected with the source (from SP maybe) it will be updated.